# Java POJO that supports unkonwn fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, pojo

I would like to create a POJO that wouldn't need to change when adding new fields to its JSON representation.

It would have some basic and required fields but will store any new fields that will be added in the future.

Examples of JSON:

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name":"udy",
    "text": "hi, my name is udy",
    "data": { "gender": "male, "age": 65, "location":{"city":"nyc"} }
}
```

I thought about creating this POJO:

```
public class Pojo{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String text;
    private Map data;
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the best option.

Couple of things in head are:

- Fast serialize/deserialize to json ([boon](https://github.com/boonproject/boon))
- Flexible support for different types (lists, objects) in data field

I know that [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) can [handle unknown fields](http://www.jasonwhaley.com/blog/2014/05/29/handling-unknown-fields-in-jackson/), however it is pretty slow [comparing to boon](http://rick-hightower.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/boon-json-parser-seems-to-be-fastest.html)

Comment: So your choice is, Stick with "fast" boon which cannot do what you want! or use Jackson (The best JSON parser available!!!!) and get the job done. Why are you more interested in performance than obtaining the desired functionallity? havent you heard?? premature optimization is the root of all evil